# How many steps do you have to show when evaluating an equation in a proof?

Tags: proof-writing

In a proof like this:
[image]

It just goes from a complicated looking expression into just $x$, is that allowed?
What are the rules for this?

Comment: There aren't rules for this sort of thing, unless you are in some context (like a classroom) where someone is imposing them.

Comment: "is that allowed?" There are no binding laws, it is rather the question, what is appropriate. I would like to see a step in between. Write $a=\sqrt{x^2-4}$ so that $a^2+4=x^2$. Then the fraction is $$ \frac{(x+a)^2+4}{2(x+a)}=\frac{x^2+2ax+(a^2+4)}{2(x+a)}=\frac{2(x+a)x}{2(x+a)}=x$$

Comment: Just a comment. What you have written is a proof that $x=\dots=x$. That's not a surprise.  But of course it isn't really a proof since the first equality is not obvious.

Comment: To my knowledge, this question has no real answer. A proof is, more or less, just a completely convincing argument. Some proofs in combinatorics, for example, are just a paragraph containing no symbolic manipulations at all.

Comment: The proof looks fine, except that like in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4700239/21813), you are begging the question by assuming the conclusion in the step "$x=$[complicated expression]". Deleting the fragment `x =` makes your proof valid. It is never valid to prove a result by assuming first assuming it.

Comment: @ryang Please correct me if im wrong but, the conclusion is "there exists number such that y+1/y=x", not "y+1/y=x". 
If i assumed the conclusion then i would be assuming that there exists y?
Is it not okay to assume the equation is true? 
In this example I think the equation is being assumed to be true: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605548/prove-that-y1-x-1y-x-iff-either-x-1-or-y-1

Comment: @enoopreuse22 You are correct, but I meant the conclusion of that section, not of the entire proof. Can you see that `x =` near the top is not merely redundant, but *invalidates* your proof? There, you aren't yet supposed to know that that equality is true; you only subsequently impicitly *derive* that equality using the transitive property of equality! $\quad$ If you (slowly) reread my linked answer to your previous question, hopefully you will become clearer about the moral of the story: no proof of an assertion begins by assuming that assertion (here the assertion is $1+\frac1y =x$).